# How to evaluate dh/dt giving dV/dt?

Tags: calculus, integration

Water evaporates from an open bowl of unspecified
shape at a rate proportional to the area ofthe water surface;
that is, $$\frac{dV}{dt} = -cA(h)$$ where V is the volume of water, A(h) is the area of the water surface when the depth is h, and c is a positive constant.

Show that $$\frac{dh}{dt} = -c$$

It gives a hint $$V=\int_{0}^{h}A(x)dx$$

I can't see how dh/dt is brought up and related to the first formula, so I have no idea what to do.

Comment: $\text{d}V=A(h)\,\text{d}h$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the hint: (and wlog)
$$\frac{dV}{dh}=A$$

By the chain rule;
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}$$
There is now sufficient information in the question for you to proceed and prove that
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=-c$$

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding. The hint is not a condition given in the statement, but just a *hint to guide the reader to think this way. So I don't think this is how it's done. And the problem then is how do you know dV/dh = A if not calculated directly from the hint.

Comment: @IvanH.Jc Hmmn. Since the shape is unspecified we can't model its volume by (say) assuming it's a half sphere. I think that the only way really is with the hint. What level is this question aimed at?

Comment: The level is elementary calculus I think... But I'm not really sure.

Comment: @IvanH.Jc Ah ok, well I am moved to say that I think the hint *must* be used in order to answer the question.